# richtextbox binding

Tags: wpf, binding, richtextbox

I have 2 `RichTextBox`es (rtb1, rtb2), I  something wrote in rtb1 and click on enter key, on this event is added text from rtb1 to rtb2. I solved this in code behind, it is possible this same write in XAML?

C# code:

```
    private void rtb2_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            var textElement = new Run() { Text = rtb2.Text };

            var paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(textElement);

            rtb1.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

            rtb2.Document.Blocks.Clear();

            //On this place I would like set start position for input text in rtb2 richtextbox on the start position
        }
    }
```

Thank for your advances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need your combined `RichTextBox` to have generalized document editing capabilities, what you are doing is probably the easiest and no, there is no pure-XAML way to do it.

On the other hand, if you are writing a chat application or something like it there may be a much better way to do it:  Replace your combined `RichTextBox` with an `ItemsControl` that displays all the chat items as individual items.  Then when Enter is pressed, add the text to a collection in your model.  As long as the collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, the new text will appear in your `ItemsControl`.  And if the template you use for your `ItemsControl` allows editing, your user will be able to edit the item.

Which way you go all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.